# How to set ImageHyperlink to have title and description like in the welcome page?

Tags: eclipse, hyperlink, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to draw an `ImageHyperlink` that looks exactly like the ones in
Eclipse's welcome page where the text consists of bold title and
description but I can't find this feature in the `ImageHyperlink` widget
itself, do I have to override the `paintHyperlink()` myself ? if so, could
someone provide a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If I read the source correctly (and it is very complex) the welcome page is actually done using HTML and not `ImageHyperlink`.

You an override the `paintHyperlink` method of `ImageHyperlink`:

```
protected void paintHyperlink(GC gc, Rectangle bounds)
```

so you should be able to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Or, as an option, you can try to mimic appearance, by using standard approach of creating composites (just style it as you wish;)):

```
private void demoHyperlinks() {
    form.getBody().setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Composite container = new Composite(form.getBody(), SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    ImageHyperlink imageHyperlink = toolkit.createImageHyperlink(container, SWT.NULL);
    imageHyperlink.setText("This is an image hyperlink.");
    imageHyperlink.setForeground(getShell().getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
    imageHyperlink.setFont(new Font(form.getDisplay(), new FontData("Verdana", 20, SWT.BOLD)));
    imageHyperlink.setImage(new Image(getShell().getDisplay(), "images/help.gif"));
    imageHyperlink.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Image hyperlink activated.");
        }
    });

    Composite descriptionContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
    gl.marginLeft = 25;
    descriptionContainer.setLayout(gl);
    Hyperlink hyperlink = toolkit.createHyperlink(descriptionContainer, "This is a hyperlink link", SWT.NULL);
    hyperlink.setForeground(getShell().getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

    HyperlinkGroup group = new HyperlinkGroup(getShell().getDisplay());
    group.add(imageHyperlink);
    group.add(hyperlink);
    group.setHyperlinkUnderlineMode(HyperlinkSettings.UNDERLINE_NEVER);

}
```